# Docker compose MySql initialisation scripts not executing

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I am having a problem having the mysql container to run my initialisation scripts.

I have two files **`create.sql`** and **`insert.sql`**, which I use to initialise the database.

I create the images using the command **`docker-compose.yml`** and it runs successfully and creates the images.

I am facing two problems.

1. When I run the **`docker-compose up`** command, the mysql container is created and started successfully. However the two initialisation scripts (**`create.sql`** and **`insert.sql`**) don't run on the database.
2. I explicitly use the **`docker run`** command to run the created mysql container. In this scenario the initialisation scripts run **successfully**.

I am using **Docker** version **18.09.0** and **docker-compose** version **1.23.1** and ubuntu **16.04** LTS

I am new to docker and can't seem to figure out the problem.

---

The following are the files I am using to create images.

**`docker-compose.yml`** file.

```
version: '3'

services:
  demo-mysql:
    image: demo-mysql
    build: ./demo-mysql
    volumes:
      - /mnt/data/mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=demo
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root

  demo-api:
    image: demo-api-1.0
    build: ./api
    depends_on:
      - demo-mysql
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=demo-mysql
      - DATABASE_USER=root
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=root
      - DATABASE_NAME=demo
      - DATABASE_PORT=3306

  demo1-app:
    image: demo1-app-1.0
    build: ./demo1
    depends_on:
      - demo-mysql
    ports:
      - 8090:8090
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=demo-mysql
      - DATABASE_USER=root
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=root
      - DATABASE_NAME=demo
      - DATABASE_PORT=3306
```

The following is the **`Dockerfile`** for the spring boot project

```
FROM java:8

VOLUME /tmp

ARG DATA_PATH=/src/main/resources
ARG APP_PORT=8080

EXPOSE ${APP_PORT}

ADD /build/libs/demo-api.jar demo-api.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","demo-api.jar"]
```

The following is the **`Dockerfile`** I used to create my mysql image

```
FROM mysql:5.7

ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=demo \
    MYSQL_USER=root \
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root

ADD ./1.0/create.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
ADD ./1.0/insert.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

EXPOSE 3306
```

Answer (score 1):

From documentation (https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/)

> Initializing a fresh instance
>
> When a container is started **for the first time**, a new database with
>   the specified name will be created and initialized with the provided
>   configuration variables. Furthermore, it will execute files with
>   extensions .sh, .sql and .sql.gz that are found in
>   /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d.

I suspect that, because of the persisted volume

```
volumes:
      - /mnt/data/mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
```

when docker starts the mysql image, there is already a DB. So the image isn't "fresh" and the scripts are not run.

**Update**:
we can confirm this suspect looking at the source code of the `docker-entrypoint.sh` here: https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/696fc899126ae00771b5d87bdadae836e704ae7d/5.7/docker-entrypoint.sh

```
if [ ! -d "$DATADIR/mysql" ]; then
...
...
        ls /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ > /dev/null
        for f in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*; do
            process_init_file "$f" "${mysql[@]}"
        done
```

The scripts run only if the `"$DATADIR/mysql"` is not present already.

btw, I personally consider a better design to have the "application" create the database schema, preload the required application data, manage schema migrations etc... at startup, but this another topic :)